# Why cast pointer into void

Tags: pointers

I came across some code. Right after the construction, the author casts the pointer into a void type. What is the purpose of this line? Is it like `assert( m_some_class_ptr != 0)` to check the integrity of the pointer?

```
Some_class * m_some_class_ptr = new Some_class();

(void)m_some_class_ptr;
```

Thank you.

Comment: can't be sure without seeing more code, but that's usually done to get rid of the "variable set but not used" warning from the compiler.

Comment: you know what, i think you are right. These pointers are all global variables (evil, i know), which are not used in the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast to void is a common idiom to avoid compiler warnings that a variable is unused. If the initialisation was the only use of m_some_class_ptr, you would quite possible get a warning. So you want to add a second use of the variable, but without doing anything.

(void)m_some_class_ptr; does nothing. It evaluates the expression m_some_class_ptr and throws the result away.